# Why we need password while converting pkcs8 key from pem to der

Tags: openssl, cryptography, pem, pkcs#8, asn.1

As pem is just base64 encoding of der. why do we need password while converting from one encoding to the other? 
if I read the certificate with code in a byte array in java (encapsulation boundaries removed) and write that byte array to a file, wouldn't that be a der file?
I tried it and it didnt work.

I'm using pkcs8 password protected keys, with aes256

Answer (score 2):

The answer why the conversion doesn't work is probably because the DER encoded file contains both the inner as well as the outer PKCS#8 structure. The inner structure defines which key was wrapped and the wrapped key itself; it's the part that gets encrypted.

The outer structure defines the protocol used to derive the wrapping key and the wrapping algorithm. If you have this structure in PEM format it is likely that the PEM header lines define the algorithms and that the base 64 encoded structure only contains the ciphertext over the inner PKCS#8 structure.

Still, is should be possible to leave the inner structure intact, as long as the encryption format and salt isn't changed. If a password is asked for it may be because of two reasons:

1. simply because it is easier because the functions to wrap and unwrap are already present in full;
2. as to change the salt or IV, so that identical wrapped keys will still generate different ciphertext (it is impossible to see that the same key was wrapped).

Comment: This is a little bit based on educated guesswork; if you want to have a more precise answer you will have to show your code and test input / output.

Comment: as for the header lines as the key is pkcs#8 it has only, BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY and END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY. not something like in pkcs#1 encrypted key which has additional information. like Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,C4A3EEC3D7782FBA34A43F2397358A62

Comment: 1 and 2 are somewhat convincing, still doesn't explain why it didnt work in java program. As for the code I cant share it here but it involves reading the pem file with headers removed in a byte[] and writing the same byte[] with FIleOutputStream. all in Java

Comment: can you help me out here ?

Comment: Java itself doesn't handle password protected PKCS#8 structures. However, to convert you should just be able to base 64 decode the contents and write that to a file. As you are not willing to share anything (which is commonly reason to close the question, by the way) I cannot and will not help you any further though. Good luck.